# How do I set focus to the top of a page without Javascript?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor, mudblazor

Is there a way to go to the top of a page in Blazor without using JavaScript? I have a list of items and the user can click on one to edit and see more details at the top of the page. I am using MudBlazor for my components.

Comment: Seeming as you can't use Blazor at all without JavaScript, why are you asking this? Also, you can't "focus" part of the page, you can only _scroll to_ a point on the page - only `<form>` controls (e.g. `<input>`, etc) and elements with `tabindex` can be focused.

Answer (score 4):

With .NET 5.0 you have now FocusAsync()

```
<input @ref="exampleInput" />
<button @onclick="ChangeFocus">Focus the Input Element</button>
@code {
    private ElementReference exampleInput;
    private async Task ChangeFocus()
    {
        await exampleInput.FocusAsync();
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#focus-an-element

Comment: Does focus move to the top of the page?

Comment: It sets focus to where ever you put the input. Unfortunately, this does not work for MudBlazor MudText fields. I have put in a request to the MudBlazor team to add this functionality.

Comment: Actually, this does work with MudBlazor! Look at the Focus section on this page -  https://mudblazor.com/components/textfield  My mistake was I tried a MudText when I should have tried a MudTextField.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the top of the page I used the NavigationManager to NavigateTo the same page with forceLoad set to false (the default value)

```
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/{currentpage}");
```

It is a bit of a bodge but it works and does not reload the page.